# Saving GPS points without database

Tags: android, gps, maps

Can I save GPS points in android without using database? 
I want first to track user's position then to reverse his track, so I need to save tracked points in order to traverse them.

Comment: Use `SharedPreferences`.

Answer (score 0):

You can always write your data to a file, following whatever format suits you (XML, JSON, or your own custom-made format)

See [Using internal storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) and [Using external storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) guides.
Depending on the size of the resulting file, it might be better to use External storage, which often has more space.

Also, maybe you have some specific reasons to not use a database, but I think using SQLite is easier to manage than file for storing data. See [Using database](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) guide for more information

Comment: Thanks for the ans.,that is because I face some problems in database,I tried to solve but it didn't work
Really If you know about drawing in android answer this question here:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15234798/draw-lines-between-gps-coordinates)